# How are passwords and salts combined with MD5 in Java and Postgres SQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, md5, salt

I'm having some trouble using salts with MD5.  I'm using both SQL (with Postgres 9.2) and Java, and I can't figure out how the salt and the unencrypted password are being combined.  Here's the Java code I'm using:

```
PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
System.out.println(encoder.encodePassword("userP@ss", "My_$3cr3t-$4lT"));
```

Which gives the result:

```
fac5ed68dd60573a4eb90760f02f5f5c
```

But then when I use SQL to do the same thing:

```
insert into account (email_address, account_name, password, phone_number, enabled)
   values ('user@freewheelers.com', 'UserCat', md5(CONCAT('userP@ss','My_$3cr3t-$4lT')), '', true);
```

Which gives the result:

```
c7d3665f9d5bebf959b0a890d0b75a9e
```

It is very important in this case to be able to replicate with the SQL what the Java is doing, or vice versa.  Does anyone know how the SQL and the Java combine the password and the salt?

Also, I know that I should be using BCrypt or some other algorithm, but in this case it is necessary to use MD5 + salt.

Thank you!

Comment: You **really** should not be using MD5 to hash passwords. No excuse.

Comment: Show us the implementation of `Md5PasswordEncoder#encodePassword()`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is a part of Spring (org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder)

Comment: Should the beginning "U" in the password be uppercase or lowercase? You have them different in each call.

Comment: @splungebob Sorry about that. I edited it. The problem still remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

You may have 2 different character encodings (UTF-8, ISO-8859, etc.), which will cause different results for the same encryption.

Is there a reason you need to encrypt in both Java and SQL?

Why not just do the encryption in Java and then just use SQL to store the encryption?

Using SQL to encrypt may present a problem if you have to change db vendors down the road and that new vendor either encrypts differently or not at all. Using Java (or whatever language you're using) to do the encryption gives you control of the implementation of the encryption.  This will make for repeatable/consistent encryptions, and will allow you to change your implementation should a newer encryption algorithm come about.